# sql-maven-plugin not creating tables in correct mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, maven, unit-testing, sql-maven-plugin

I have tried many different variations of the code below (including extracting the Database connection details into the  tag), but no matter what I do, the table is still created in the wrong database.

I have also tried to execute the "use autofi" database, but that does not work either and the tables are still created in a different database.

```xml
<plugin>
    <!-- Used to automatically drop (if any) and create a database prior to running integration test cases. -->
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.5</version>
        </dependency>             
    </dependencies>


    <configuration> <!-- I'VE TRIED TAKING THIS OUT AS WELL -->
      <!-- common configuration shared by all executions -->
      <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</url>
      <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
      <username>root</username>
      <password>root</password>
    </configuration>


    <executions>
      <execution>
        <!-- and finally run the schema creation script we just made with the hibernate3-maven-plugin -->
        <id>create-schema</id>
        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/AUTOFI</url>
          <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
          <username>root</username>
          <password>root</password>     
          <srcFiles>
            <srcFile>src/test/resources/sql/schema.sql</srcFile>
          </srcFiles>
          <onError>continue</onError>
        </configuration>
      </execution>


      <!-- drop db after test -->
      <execution>
        <id>drop-db-after-test</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</url>
          <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
          <username>root</username>
          <password>root</password>     
          <autocommit>true</autocommit>
          <sqlCommand>drop database AUTOFI;</sqlCommand>
        </configuration>
      </execution>


    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

I have used the maven-sql-plugin examples as a template and that did not work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks, 
    Sean

Comment: There were multiple pieces that were messed up in my configuration.  The error was confusing and somewhat of a red-herring: User table does not exist.  So I finally thought to update the JPAPropertyMap config by setting hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto equal to simple "validate".  This revealed that the table was being created in the right spot, but I received a much more informative error: ID column does not exist.  I was using USER_ID instead of just ID.  Once I fixed the column issue, I was able to then utilize the sql-maven-plugin pieces just like their usage states.